# invalid type argument of '->' (have 'int')

Tags: c, pointers, dereference, operator-precedence, invalid-argument

I get the error reported below while I am compiling my code. Could you please correct me where I mistaken?

> invalid type argument of `->` (have `int`)

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct bundles
    {
    char str[12];
    struct bundles *right;
}bundle;

int main() {

    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */    
    unsigned long N;
    scanf("%lu", &N);
    bundle *arr_nodes;
    arr_nodes = malloc(sizeof(bundle)*100);
    int i=5;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
    scanf("%s", &arr_nodes+i->str);
    printf("%s", arr_nodes+i->str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am facing issues at these lines:

```
scanf("%s", &arr_nodes+i->str);
printf("%s", arr_nodes+i->str);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean

```
scanf("%s", (arr_nodes+i)->str);
```

without parentheses the `->` operator was being applied to `i` instead of the increased pointer, that notation is often confusing, specially because this

```
scanf("%s", arr_nodes[i].str);
```

would do exactly the same.

You should also, check that `malloc()` didn't return `NULL` and verify that `scanf()` did scan succesfully.

Comment: Thanks iharob. It worked. I was unaware of the parentheses. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
scanf("%s", (arr_nodes+i)->str);
printf("%s", (arr_nodes+i)->str);
```

Your original code was the same as

```
scanf("%s", &arr_nodes+ (i->str) );
```

because the `->` has a higher precedence than `+`, so you get that error.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), `->` is having higher precedence over `+`. You need to change your code to

```
scanf("%s", (arr_nodes+i)->str);
```